# I want to filter by Today Day and Count ids on that day

Tags: python, django

I am New To Django Plz help me out 
But in this Case I want Result as

```
{weekday: todayweek_number, count: total_ids_count_number }
```

Currently I am Using this Django Query as follows

```
 Booking.objects.filter(created_at__day=today.day).annotate(count=Count('id')).values('weekday', 'count')
```

The Point here is 'Weekday' I want Today Week Day Number as a key, which I am Using in filter

Model:

```
consultation_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="OFFLINE", choices=CONSULTATION)
  conversation_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="HOMEVISIT", choices=CONVERSATION)
  patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient,verbose_name=_('Patient'), null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, verbose_name=_('Doctor'), null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  visit_address = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Address'))
  appointment_at = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('Appointment at'),editable=True, blank=True,null=True)
  estimated_cost = models.FloatField(verbose_name=_('Estimated Cost'),default=0,validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(99999)])
  booking_status = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Booking Status'), max_length=50, default= "WAITING", choices=BOOKINGSTATUS)
  cancel_reason = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Cancel Reason'),max_length=200)
  comment = models.TextField(verbose_name=_('Comment'))
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  service = models.ForeignKey(to="doctors.Services", verbose_name=_('Service'), null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  child = models.ManyToManyField(verbose_name=_('Child'),to="patients.Child", blank=True)
  payment_status = models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Payment Status'),max_length=50, default= "PENDING", choices=BOOKINGPAYMENTSTATUS)
```

Error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'weekday' into field.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is database function called [**`ExtractWeekDay`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.ExtractWeekDay) provided by django. You can use it like this:

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractWeekDay

Booking.objects.filter(created_at__day=today.day).annotate(count=Count('id'),weekday=ExtractWeekDay('created_at')).values('weekday', 'count')
```

---

### Update

From comments of OP, as far as I know, you can't do it like `[0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` using queryset. But with a loop, you can achieve it like this:

```
bookings = list(Booking.objects.filter(created_at__day=today.day).annotate(count=Count('id'),weekday=ExtractWeekDay('created_at')).values_list('weekday','count'))

weekdays = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
for i in bookings:
    weekdays[i[0]] = i[1]
```

**OR** simply use the following code:

```
weekdays = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
weekdays[today.weekday()] = Booking.objects.filter(created_at__day=today.day).count()
previous_day = today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
weekdays[previous_day.weekday()] = Booking.objects.filter(created_at__day=previous_day.day).count()
```

Comment: Sir Yes This Thing I Want, But Now I have One Question this query will Provide Only Today Day and the Count of Today , But This Will Only Show the today data in graph , What if we what Previous days Count also, SO the Admin will measure the data on which day booking will goes down

Answer (score 0):

**Update code:**

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractWeekDay
from datetime import date
today = date.today()

Mymodel.objects.filter(created_at__day=today.day).annotate(count=Count('id'),weekday=ExtractWeekDay('created_at')).values('weekday', 'count')
```

**Result:**

```
{'count': 1, 'weekday': 2}
```

Comment: Updated Successfuly  Now Check.. When I add DateFiedl same error occur

Answer (score 0):

If you using Django 2, then you can be using ExtractWeekDay to group the field and count how many.

like:

```
from django.db.models.functions import ExtractWeekDay
Booking.objects.filter(created_at__day=today.day).annotate(weekday=ExtractWeekDay('created_at')).values('weekday').annotate(count=Count('id')).values('weekday', 'count')
```